# flash cs3 Unexpected file format when trying to open a .fla file

Tags: flash, cs3

I am using flash cs3 pro and I get the error "Unexpected file format" when trying to open the file, i failed opening the same in CS4 and CS5 as well

Is there something I could do to open this .fla file correctly?

Or maybe if someone could try opening it and saving it again for cs3?

If the file is corrupted is there any way to recover my file(my OS is Windows 8)

thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the source *.fla file will not open with the very latest Flash Pro version CS 6 (download a trial if needed).

If it still does not work you can try extracting your .fla's assets and throwing them into a new project. Some links that explain this process include [Getting library assets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453942/1091955) and [9 Steps to fix corrupt .fla file](http://www.downloadatoz.com/howto/how-to-fix-corrupt-fla-file-on-adobe-flash-cs5,11482.html).